# boolean field and value assignment for single optional assignment

Tags: xtext

Is there an easy way to have a in the final model a boolean field for a optional attribute AND a value assignment?
For example like this:

```
Enum:
    name=ID assigned=( '(' value=INT ')' )?
;
```

My goal is to have an enum type similar to C where if you do not specify the enum value explicitly it will count from 0 or the last specified value.

I guess I need to compute the final values in a later step, but there I would need the information which of the values were given by the user.

Maybe there is even an easier solution to this...

Comment: Am not sure if I get you requirement but name=ID ( assigned?='(' value=INT ')')?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Now I feel silly that I didn't manage to do it yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `?=` operator

```
Enum: name=ID (assigned?='(' value=INT ')')?;
```